# CRON on synology DS214se NAS

Tags: php, cron, synology

I have problem with adding CRON rules to synology DS214se.

1. I add line to /etc/crontab

   `* * * * * root /volume1/web/gym/bin/cron/cronTabTest.php`
2. Save crontab and restart him with

   `/usr/syno/sbin/synoservicectl --restart crond`
3. Restart NAS box.
4. After restart command line is in /etc/crontab but doesnt work.

What im doing wrong? Please help me.

This is cronTabTest.php:

```
    <?php

$file = 'test.txt';
file_put_contents($file, date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' ',FILE_APPEND);
echo 'cron';

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your cron line is missing `php` at the beginning. Change the line

```
* * * * * root /volume1/web/gym/bin/cron/cronTabTest.php
```

to

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /volume1/web/gym/bin/cron/cronTabTest.php
```

Second, when working on the cli, you will need to make sure to provide the full path from your server's root for all your files you are calling. For example:

```
$file = '/volume1/web/gym/bin/cron/test.txt';
file_put_contents($file, date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' ',FILE_APPEND);
echo 'cron';
```